# clone aria-label text from one div to another

Tags: jquery

I need to grab the content/text from aria-label on one div ie "modal-form details" and apply it to another div "modal-title"..

```
<div aria-hidden="false" class="modal fade modal-form modal-form-details in" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalTitleID_c86a3872-d40a-ec11-b6e6-00224808dc5a" aria-label="EARPLUG-2681 dialog" style="display: block;">
```

it should read

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">EARPLUG-2681</h4>
</div>
```

here is my best effort

```
$(".modal-form-details").attr('aria-label').clone().insertAfter(".modal-title");
```

how can this be accomplished

Comment: There is no question. Just a request for some code. What have you tried?

Comment: $(".modal-form-details").attr('aria-label').clone().insertAfter(".modal-title");
how can this be accomplished